# How can I filter xml data with xpath?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

If I have a xml file with something like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Employees> 
   <Employee Department="Sales"> 
      <Name>David</Name> 
      <Salary>20000</Salary> 
   </Employee> 
   <Employee Department="Finance"> 
      <Name>Simon</Name> 
      <Salary>18000</Salary> 
   </Employee> 
   <Employee Department="Accounts"> 
      <Name>Peter</Name> 
      <Salary>22000</Salary> 
   </Employee> 
</Employees>
```

And then the data is being displayed in a repeater like so:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <strong> 
     <%# XPath("@Department")%><br /> 
  </strong> 
  - Name: <%#XPath("Name")%><br /> 
  - Salary: <%#XPath("Salary")%><br />  
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

How could I display only the Employee in the Sales department? This is in a asp.net webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this by using XPath on the data source.

```
<asp:XmlDataSource DataFile="data.xml" runat="server" ID="XmlDataSource1" XPath="/Employees/Employee[@Department='Sales']" />

<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
   <ItemTemplate>
    <strong>Department: <%# XPath("@Department")%><br /></strong> 
    - Name: <%#XPath("Name")%><br /> 
    - Salary: <%#XPath("Salary")%><br />  
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Output**

```
Department: Sales
- Name: David
- Salary: 20000
```

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly what I was looking for, couldnt figure out how to filter and get all the values.  My query just return the same one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Data in the background using the filter as a data source
Repeater, which could not seem to